# How to setText of a TextView inside a ViewPager programmaticaly?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager

Sorry, I know that there are a lot of question about this problem but I tried every solution that I found but without success.
I'm trying to change the text of a TextView inside a ViewPager. I have the screen divided in two part: one is a ViewPager and and one is a normal layout. If I change a text that is inside the normal layout it change without problem, but if I change text that is inside the ViewPager it doesn't change. 
I have two xml layout : activity_main and fragment main created automatically from Android Studio, in OnCreate of MainActivity I have 
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

my Fragment

```
  public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.weathericon);
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temperatura_main, container, false);
        }
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.precipitazioni_main, container, false);

        }
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 4) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vento_main, container, false);
        }
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 5) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alba_main, container, false);
        }
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 6) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.umidita_main, container, false);
        }
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 7) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pressione_main, container, false);


        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

my PageAdapter

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }


    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
            case 3:
                return "SECTION 4";
            case 4:
                return "SECTION 5";
            case 5:
                return "SECTION 6";
            case 6:
                return "SECTION 7";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and I try to change the text in this way,when I have the new data:

```
 @Override
        public void success(WeatherResponse weatherResponse, Response response) {
            String forecast = weatherResponse.getCurrently().getSummary();


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,null);


            forecast1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foredesc1);


            wedesc = (TextView) layout1.findViewById(R.id.weatherdescription); //this is in fragment_main
            city = (TextView) layout1.findViewById(R.id.city);



            wedesc.setText("test"); //the problem is here
            forecast1.setText(forecast);

           /* Fragment frg = null;
            frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("container");
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            ft.detach(frg);
            ft.attach(frg);
            ft.commit();
            */



            mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

the only way I found to change the text if add 
`setContentView(layout1)`

but the problem is that in this way I don't have anymore the ViewPager and the other layout, only the content in fragment_main xml.

I don't know if I explained well but where is the problem?

Comment: Yes,sorry I have already set the adatper in on create with

Comment: ' mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);'

Comment: Sorry, you can just ignore everything above. The problem is, you havent changed the content of the viewpager. You are setting: wedesc.setText("test"), where wedesc is in the new layout you created.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand very well, could you show me some code please?

Comment: How can I change the content of the ViewPager?

Comment: You should make 7 separate Fragment classes instead of using a single class to load 7 different layouts. And you return those different classes from the adapter based on the position. In order to change the content of the ViewPager, you update its adapter

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i'm new and i'm 14 so i don't know very code, anyway how can i do this? I have to create 7 activity.Java?

Comment: Ah okey thank you, but i update the adapter with setAdapter?

Comment: It doesn'work. I created a class even for the pagerAdapter and I implement this with:     `  mSectionsPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
`
I created a class for each fragment and I try to refresh with: `mViewPager.setAdapter(null);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);`